# SimpleXML parsing through namespace items with ->children

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, namespaces, attributes

I am parsing through the following XML file:

**testxml.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><document>
<node id="n0">
  <data key="d6">
    <y:GenericNode configuration="TEXT I WANT TO GET">
      <y:Geometry height="56.030557066666574" width="181.68810666666667" x="638.4599149206349" y="143.24969103333325"/>
      <y:Fill color="#FFCC66" color2="#FF9900" transparent="false"/>
      <y:BorderStyle color="#000000" type="line" width="1.0"/>
      <y:NodeLabel alignment="center" autoSizePolicy="node_width" configuration="CroppingLabel" fontFamily="Dialog" fontSize="12" fontStyle="plain" hasBackgroundColor="false" hasLineColor="false" height="34.265625" horizontalTextPosition="center" iconTextGap="4" modelName="custom" textColor="#000000" verticalTextPosition="bottom" visible="true" width="181.68810666666667" x="0.0" y="10.882466033333287">Text I want to Get<y:LabelModel>
          <y:SmartNodeLabelModel distance="4.0"/>
        </y:LabelModel>
        <y:ModelParameter>
          <y:SmartNodeLabelModelParameter labelRatioX="-0.5" labelRatioY="0.0" nodeRatioX="-0.5" nodeRatioY="0.0" offsetX="0.0" offsetY="0.0" upX="0.0" upY="-1.0"/>
        </y:ModelParameter>
      </y:NodeLabel>
    </y:GenericNode>
  </data>
</node>
```

I am interested in only a handful of attributes, namely the node id, data key which I am able to get with the code below. However, when I move into the y: namespace I get nothing.

**xmlparser.php**

```
<?php 
$xml = simplexml_load_file("testxml.xml") 
or die("Error: Cannot create object - check that the XML file exists and is             
not corrupted"); print_r($xml);
echo  $xml->node[0]['id'];   // This works
echo  $xml->node[0]->data[0]['key']; // This works

echo $xml->children('y', true)->GenericNode->attributes()->configuration;  // Nothing

echo $xml->children('y', true)->GenericNode->NodeLabel; // Nothing

?>
```

I've read through previous answers on similar issues, based on which I adopted the children approach. However I can't get this to work, and I have no idea how to implement some of the other approaches such as declaring namespaces and the xpath approach.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `y:GenericNode` isn't direct child of the root element, so you shouldn't be accessing it directly from `$xml` :

```
$xml->node->data->children('y', true)->GenericNode->attributes()->configuration;
```

quick test : https://eval.in/761412